# How to execute Word VBA code through Python script?

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, vbe

I'm trying to execute a macro in a Word file using Python and the pywin32 module.

My Python script opens the Word file, creates a new VBA module in the project, and tries to execute the macro from the NewMacros.bas file.

When executing the script, various errors occur, such as "Compile error: Syntax error", "Run-time error '4198'", etc.
I checked the macro file for syntax errors, installed the latest version of pywin32 and checked permissions to execute macros.

Here is my Python script code and the contents of the `NewMacros.bas` macro file:

VBA code:

```vb
Sub IterateThroughPictures()
    Dim shp As inlineShape
    
    ' Перебираем все встроенные фотографии и рисунки в документе
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If shp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            ' Выделяем текущую фотографию или рисунок
            shp.Select
            
            ' Выполняем код для текущей фотографии или рисунка
            Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Рисунок", TitleAutoText:="InsertCaption2", _
                Title:="", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0
                
            ' Редактируем название фотографии
            With shp.Range
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Черный цвет
                .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            End With
            
            ' Снимаем выделение с фотографии или рисунка
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Python Script:

```
import win32com.client
import time

# Создаем объект приложения Word
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

# Открываем документ
time.sleep(2)  # Задержка в 2 секунды
doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\felix\Downloads\test\111.docx")

# Получаем объект VBProject, представляющий проект VBA в документе
vb_project = doc.VBProject

# Создаем новый модуль в проекте VBA
module = vb_project.VBComponents.Add(1)

# Устанавливаем имя модуля
module.Name = "NewMacros"

# Загружаем содержимое макроса из файла NewMacros.bas
with open('NewMacros.bas', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()

# Записываем код макроса в модуль
module.CodeModule.AddFromString(code)

# Выполняем макрос
word.Application.Run("NewMacros.ApplyStyleToCaptions")
word.Application.Run("NewMacros.IterateThroughPictures")

# Save and close the document
doc.Save()
doc.Close()

# Close the Word application
word.Quit()
```

I run the script:

```
python .\test.py
```

On the first run, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\Downloads\test\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    word.Application.Run("NewMacros.ApplyStyleToCaptions")
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Run
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 366, in _ApplyTypes_
    result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Не удалось запустить указанный макрос', 'wdmain11.chm', 37401, -2147352573), None)
```

On the second run, a Word file opens, no changes occur in it, but another error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\Downloads\test\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    module.Name = "NewMacros"
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 685, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146795475), None)
```

Version python 3.11.1